# postgres bad connection localhost

Tags: ruby, postgresql

On UBUNTU, I have a ruby app with a postgresql database on my localhost.
Everything was working fine yesterday, but today my database was gone. I was still able to open the app. Then I got an error saying something like,

`run rails db:migrate`

After I ran the command I started getting

```
PG::ConnectionBad at /
    server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

None of the config files were changed since yesterday.
I use docker-compose up to start the server and apparently it starts the connection but I still cannot access my localhost.

What could be the problem here?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the logs in your DB, if the DB is running on docker as well then maybe it's not finishing the DB boot correctly.

If this is the case, run the DB container manually first with the same options as in your docker-compose and then check `docker logs` for that container.

Comment: It was a docker problem, all I had to do was run: **sudo service restart docker** . Then docker-compose up loaded everything just fine.